# Dismiss an Alertdialog in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I am trying to dismiss an AlertDialog in android:

```
    public AlertDialog dialog;
             AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Message."); 
                dialog= builder.create();
                dialog.show();
  Thread thread = new Thread(this);
  thread.start();

        public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        //some code
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        Looper.loop();
        }

        Handler handler= new Handler() {

            @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            { dialog.dismiss();
            //some code 
            } 
            };
```

It doesn't work. I have searched and tried several proposed methods, and they were all unsuccessful.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post few more code where you are calling and Dismiss Dialog.

Comment: from where are you dismissing the dialog

Comment: refer this site, http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: @  Krishnakant Dalal and @  Vipin Sahu: I have edited my question.

Comment: put your break point in run method where you trying to send message to handler. and also put inside handleMessage method.

Answer (score 0):

Please use ProgressDailog instead of alert.

```
To create:



 ProgressDailog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading ..", "Please Wait..");

To dismiss:

progressDialog.dismiss();
```

to cancel alert Use below code

```
dialog.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
```